# OpenGL - setting visible area

Tags: opengl

**EDIT**: *So it seems glOrtho does what I was trying to do (set the area you want to view), the error was in my code. However, it might be a common beginner error so someone might still find this useful*

I'm using glOrtho (I figure it should be easier to setup orthographic projection than perspective). Anyhow, I am drawing small cubes (1x1x1) in an area (all my visible area) of 500x500x500. How do I tell OpenGL (using openGL 2) to draw on screen everything that is in the area (500,500,500)?

This is my code - it is in Java, but it should work the same ...

```
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) 
{
    final GL2 gl = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();

    if (height <= 0) // avoid a divide by zero error!
    {
        height = 1;
    }

    final float h = (float) width / (float) height;

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrtho(0, 512, 0, 512, 0, 512);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}
```

This does not seem to do the trick, I can only see a few squares instead of hundreds ...

Here is my cube drawing code (all coordinates of all cubes are between 0 and 500):

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) 
{
    final GL2 gl = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    for(InterestingVoxel iv: visibleList) {
        gl.glTranslatef(iv.getI(), iv.getJ(), iv.getK());
        System.out.println("x:"+iv.getI() + ", y:" + iv.getJ() + ", z:" + iv.getK());
        drawCube(gl);
    }


}

void drawCube(GL2 gl)
{
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);

    // front
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.5f, 0.5f);
    // back
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.5f, -0.5f);
    // right
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.5f, 0.5f);
    // left
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.5f, 0.5f);
    // top
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.5f, -0.5f);
    // bottom
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
    gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);

    gl.glEnd();
    gl.glFlush();
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. Can we see your cubes-drawing code as well?

Comment: Sure ... Just added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `glTranslate` calls are accumulating, which puts most of your cubes well out beyond 512.  Perhaps you wanted to use the matrix stack, or else use `glLoadIdentity` inside the loop.

Comment: You are right - I had to use glLoadIdentity inside the loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're asking how to restrict drawing to a specific area. If not and this is a more general-purpose "my code doesn't work" question, you can probably disregard this answer.

Since you're using GL 2.x, you might want to look into using [`ClipPlane`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glClipPlane.xml) to clip drawing to a specific region. So, in your case, (Depending on what the data you're passing to GL is) you'd probably want to pass either 3 to 6 clip planes and enable them (`Enable(CLIP_PLANEi)` where *`i`* is the clip plane index/number).

For example (pseudocode because I don't have a working GL2 testbed right now):

```
plane planes[] = {
    plane::from_triangle(
        500, 500, 500,
        500, 500, 0,
        500, 0, 500,
    ),
    plane::from_triangle(
        500, 500, 500,
        0, 500, 500,
        500, 0, 500,
    ),
    ...
}
// Assume the above is just a lot of GLdoubles somehow [e.g., POD types]

ClipPlane(6, planes)
for (unsigned plane_index = 0 to 5) {
    Enable(CLIP_PLANE0 + plane_index)
}
```

Doing that, you could reasonably confine rendering to anything on one side of the specified planes. Bear in mind though that this is deprecated (like a lot of GL 2.x), so if you plan to ever move beyond that, you'll want to probably reimplement clip planes in shaders.

Alternatively, just check what you're drawing and only draw it if it's in the area you want drawn.